# Unable to import database dump - triggers

Tags: database, trigger

I had a problem importing a database dump because of some trigger errors. I'm not sure exactly what caused these errors (may have had something to do with custom case activities, which we use quite a lot, or possibly CiviRules).

I tried deleting the triggers from the dump file using the awk script below, and then imported the new de-triggered dump file. Is there anything wrong with this approach? It seemed to work for me.

Btw I adapted the awk code from a post on [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/858242/text-deletion-between-patterns-across-multiple-lines-with-respect-to-text-inside).

Run the awk script as follows: 
awk -f scriptfilename databasefilename > outputfilename

awk script:

```
BEGIN { curr=0 } \
  /^DELIMITER ;;$/ { in_block=1; del_block=0 } \
  /^DELIMITER ;$/ { in_block=0; blockend=1 } \
  /TRIGGER/ { if (in_block==1) { del_block=1 } } \
  { if (in_block==0) \
    { if (blockend==0) \
      # Neither in a block nor block end reached.
      # Just print the line
      { print } \
    else { \
      # End of a block reached. Do block end handling
      # just this one time. Block end flag off
      blockend=0
        if (del_block==1) \
          { # delete the block. Just throw away the lines
          # in the lines array
          curr=0 } \
        else \
          { # End of block and no delete. Print it out
          for (i=0; i<curr; i++) { print line[i] }
          print # Print the </script> line
          # use line-array for the next block
         curr=0 \
       } \
     } \
   } \
 else \
   { # In a block. Save the current line for later
    line[curr]=$0
    curr++ } \
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our team use

```
perl -pi -e 's#\/\*\!5001[7|3].*?`[^\*]*\*\/##g'
```

Comment: Thanks. That's much neater!